# Run time error 424 Object Required working with UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, userform

I'm trying to link a user form I built in VBA editor for MS Excel 2010 to the data in an excel worksheet, but I'm getting a

> run-time error 424: Object required.

I referred to the active worksheet explicitly in my code to try and remedy this, but it still comes up with the same error. My code is:

```
Private Sub GetData()
    Dim r As Long
    r = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value

    If IsNumeric(RowNumber.Text) Then
        r = CLng(RowNumber.Text)
    Else
        ClearData
        MsgBox "Invalid row number"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If r > 1 And r <= LastRow Then
        cboFilterResultId.Text = FormatNumber(Cells(r, 1), 0)
        txtFolderPaths.Text = Cells(r, 2)
        txtFileName.Text = Cells(r, 3)
        txtDeletedDate.Text = Cells(r, 4)
        txtReason.Text = Cells(r, 5)
        txtcboAdd.Text = Cells(r, 6)
        txtcboView.Text = Cells(r, 7)
        txtcboChange.Text = Cells(r, 8)

        DisableSave   
    ElseIf r = 1 Then
        ClearData
    Else 
        ClearData
        MsgBox "Invalid row number"
    End If  
End Sub
```

Where RowNumber is a textbox where the user can enter the row number for the data they want.

Please help!

Comment: Where, in which line do you get the error?

Comment: Try putting `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and see if you can compile the code. If not then any one of your `<Object>.Text`  are spelt incorrectly.

Comment: Take a look which line gets in yellow, once you click "DEBUG" on the big grown ugly MsgBox. This line has a grammer error in the Name property, as definded in the Form element.

Comment: 424 means Object required. This error occurs if text preceding a dot is not recognized as an object.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use `ActiveSheet` just in case that isn't the sheet I'm after.  Generally better to be explicit which sheet you're referring to:
`r=ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")`

Right, pulling data from a worksheet to a userform... as you haven't said which line your error occurs on and you haven't given us the code for `ClearData` or `DisableSave` I'll start from scratch.

### Example Form Design

I create a blank userform and add three text boxes and a spin button to it:

- `txtRowNumber` holds the row number that the data is pulled from.
- `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` will hold my sample values.
  In the `Tag` property of `TextBox1` I enter `1` and in the `Tag` property of `TextBox2` I enter `2`.  These are the column numbers that the data will be pulled from.
  In reality I usually add extra stuff, for example, `8;CPER;REQD`.  I'd then use some code to pull it apart so it pastes in column 8, must have a percentage and is a required entry.
- `spnButton` is used to quickly move up or down a row.

We'll need two procedures to populate the form from the given row number and to clear all controls on the form (ready for the next row to be brought in).

Any textbox or combobox that has something in it's `Tag` property is cleared:

```
Private Sub ClearForm()

    Dim frmCtrl As Control

    For Each frmCtrl In Me.Controls
        If frmCtrl.Tag <> "" Then
            Select Case TypeName(frmCtrl)
                Case "TextBox", "ComboBox"
                    frmCtrl.Value = Null
                Case Else
                    'Do nothing.
            End Select
        End If
    Next frmCtrl

End Sub
```

Any control that has a `Tag` value (it's assumed the value is correct) is populated from the specified `RowNumber` and column (from the `Tag` value).  The value is *always* taken from the sheet called *MyDataSheet* in the workbook containing the VBA code (`ThisWorkbook`) no matter which is currently active:

```
Private Sub PopulateForm(RowNumber As Long)

    Dim frmCtrl As Control

    For Each frmCtrl In Me.Controls
        With frmCtrl
            If .Tag <> "" Then
                .Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyDataSheet").Cells(RowNumber, CLng(.Tag))
            End If
        End With
    Next frmCtrl

End Sub
```

Whenever `txtRowNumber` changes the form should update with values from the indicated row.  To do this we'll need to clear the form of current data and then repopulate it:

```
Private Sub txtRowNumber_Change()
    ClearForm
    PopulateForm CLng(Me.txtRowNumber)
End Sub
```

The spin button should increase/decrease the value in `.txtRowNumber`.  I've added checks that it doesn't go below 1.  You should also add checks that it doesn't go higher than the last populated row.

```
Private Sub spnButton_SpinDown()
    With Me
        .txtRowNumber = CLng(.txtRowNumber) + 1
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub spnButton_SpinUp()
    With Me
        If CLng(.txtRowNumber) > 1 Then
            .txtRowNumber = CLng(.txtRowNumber) - 1
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, the form should be populated when it is first opened:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Me
        .txtRowNumber = 2
        .spnButton = .txtRowNumber
        PopulateForm .txtRowNumber
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Darren, how can I extend the Private Sub UserForm_Initialize () function to populate the other fields? Instead of txtRowNumber I've used txtFilterResultId (from a column in the worksheet). At the moment it is filling txtFilterResultId with 11 but the other fields are blank. My code is now:Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Me
.txtFilterResultId = 11
.spnButton = .txtFilterResultId
Populateform .txtFilterResultId
End With
End Sub

Comment: The `Private Sub PopulateForm(RowNumber As Long)` procedure is the one that places the values into controls on the form.  In any `textbox` control that is to receive a value enter the column number in the `Tag` property of the control and the `PopulateForm` procedure will automatically pick it up.